# GLM via method of alternating projections (Gauss-Seidel)

Tags: generalized-linear-model, fixed-effects-model

Simon Gaure's "lfe" command in R estimates linear models with high dimensional fixed effects. McFadden and coauthors have an R program "bife" that does this for binary models. I am wondering whether anyone has done this for general linear models (glm) which would include poisson as one of many cases including fractional probit and logit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.01815.pdf. Software will be made available for k-way fe glm`s.